# How to get List<object> as parameter in action in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have a class which its name is "Question.cs" and I have another one that its name is "Answer.cs".
I want to send List of Questions to my action instead of one Question and I don't know how can I do it.
In fact, I don't know how to get the Questions as parameter. Can anyone tell me how I can receive the Questions in the action?
Here are my classes:

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string QuestionAnswer { get; set; }

    //property
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string AnswerTitle { get; set; }
    
    //property
    [ForeignKey("QuestionId")]
    public Question Question { get; set; } 
}
```

This is my Razor View (Question.cshtml) :

```
@using GameShop.Data.Domain.QuestIonsAnswers
@model List<GameShop.Data.Domain.QuestIonsAnswers.Question>
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
<form asp-action="Index" method="POST">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>@item.QuestionTitle</div>
        <input asp-for="@item.QuestionAnswer" Value="@item.QuestionId" />
        <br />
    }
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="ثبت">
</form>
```

As you see, I used a foreach loop which is give me all of the "Questions". So I can't receive just one "Question" in my action. These are my actions:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_context.Questions.ToList());
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Question question)
{
    foreach (var item in question)
    {
        var ans=new Answer(){
            QuestionId=item.QuestionId,
            AnswerTitle=item.QuestionAnswer
        };
        _context.Answers.Add(ans);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View(_context.Questions.ToList());
}
```

I think I have to get `List<Question>` in my second action but I don't know how?
Can anyone help me step by step?

Comment: Not sure about your actual end in mind intention. Do you want to show only one question on your page and submit only one answer? Do you want to show multiple questions on your page and individually submit each answer? Do you want to show multiple questions on your page and submit all the answers at once?

Comment: I want to show all of my Questions and submit them at once. Assume that I have 3 Questions in my Table. I wanna show all of them and then submit all of them to the action (Index) at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the following steps to modify your code:

1. In the View page, use `for` loop to loop through the Model and display the value. code like this:

   ```
    @model List<WebApplication6.Models.Question>

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    } 
    <h1>Index</h1> 
    <form asp-action="Index" method="POST">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div>@Model[i].QuestionTitle</div>
                <input asp-for="@Model[i].QuestionId" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@Model[i].QuestionTitle" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@Model[i].QuestionAnswer" />
                <br />
            } 
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="ثبت">
    </form>
   ```
2. In the Post method, change the parameter data type to `List<Question>`.

   ```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(List<Question> questions)
    {
        foreach (var item in questions)
        {
            //var ans = new Answer()
            //{
            //    QuestionId = item.QuestionId,
            //    AnswerTitle = item.QuestionAnswer
            //};
            //_context.Answers.Add(ans);
            //_context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(_context.Questions.ToList());
    }
   ```

Then, the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the thing i was looking for.